# Use ADO.NET and XML in ASP.NET C# Web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, ado.net

I am new to ASP.NET webforms and C#. I want to create a simple web application with the function of searching a specific student name from the XML document. The web app has a textbox where i can type the student name or id and click submit button it should retrieve the data of the student from the XML. How do i make this search function work form XML? The data user recieves should be independent not in gridview format, so i can style them to look like a graduation certificate.

Here is the sample that i have made:
[SampleStudentGraduation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXXQB.png)

This is how i want to make it look like:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH6py.png)

This is the XML document

```
<Graduate>

<Student>
<ID> 01944422</ID>
<Student_Name>Peter Parker</Student_Name>
<Honours> First Class </Honours>
<Book_Price>Yes</Book_Price>
<Programme>Comp. Science</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
<ID>01923455</ID>
<Student_Name>Bryan Adam</Student_Name>
<Honours>Second class</Honours>
<Book_Price>No</Book_Price>
<Programme>Mathematics</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
<ID>01952345</ID>
<Student_Name>Maggie Fong</Student_Name>
<Honours>First class</Honours>
<Book_Price>Yes</Book_Price>
<Programme>Accounting</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
<ID>01998745</ID>
<Student_Name>Melissa Teh</Student_Name>
<Honours>First class</Honours>
<Book_Price>Yes</Book_Price>
<Programme>Finance</Programme>
</Student>


<Student>
<ID>01899888</ID>
<Student_Name>Ahmad bin Suhail</Student_Name>
<Honours>Second class</Honours>
<Book_Price>No</Book_Price>
<Programme>Engineering</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
<ID>01900847</ID>
<Student_Name>Lechumanan a/l Vicky</Student_Name>
<Honours>Third class</Honours>
<Book_Price>No</Book_Price>
<Programme>Comp. Science</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
<ID>04503967</ID>
<Student_Name>Soo Tong Wei</Student_Name>
<Honours>Third class</Honours>
<Book_Price>No</Book_Price>
<Programme>Mathematics</Programme>
</Student>

</Graduate>
```

Comment: Before you go any further, are you aware that WebForms is not a technology that you use for new projects anymore? If you are going to learn something choose a modern framework.

Comment: yes I am aware of that, im just trying to learn something from C#. is there any modern frameworks you recommend

Comment: OK, fair enough. You have a choice whether you want to use the [XmlDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource?view=netframework-4.8) or just read the xml and search for your record. Your choice, but if you do not plan on allowing edits to the data then you would learn more c# by doing some [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will choose LINQ to XML I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the xml to a dataset, then everything becomes a walk in the park.

So, this markup:

```
<div>
    <h1>Student Graduation</h1>
        Search for 
        <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" Text="Search!" runat="server" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" 
            CssClass="btn" style="margin-left:15px"       />

    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="40%">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And the code for the search button:

protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string sFile  = @"C:\Test7\sData.txt";
DataSet MyData = new DataSet();
MyData.ReadXml(sFile);

```
    // if blank, then show all data
    DataTable MyTable = MyData.Tables[0];
    if (SearchTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        string s = SearchTextBox.Text;
        // user entered somthing
        // if text, then match on stuent name

        if (s.All(char.IsNumber))
        {
            // number, lets filter by ID
            MyTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = " + s;
        }
        else
        {
            // search Student name - partial match
            MyTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Student_Name like '%" + s + "%'";
        }
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

So, if we enter nothing, then we show all and see this:

[image]

nd I used a wild card search for the name - we could I suppose JUST match on say the start, but you can say search for "B", and you get this:

[image]

Of course, if you enter a number, then I search by ID, and say this

[image]

And I suppose we should add to the GV a "no data row, say like this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="40%">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <h2>No data found</h2>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

However, as noted, you do NOT want a grid format results.

So, we can just change the GV to say a repeoater, or datalist.

Lets use a data list.

So, our markup now becomes this:

```
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" >
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

The code remains as before, execpt for this:

```
        DetailsView1.DataSource = MyTable;
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
```

And we now have the results in a FORM type of layout:

[image]

So be it a grid, or even just filling out controls on a page, the approach is quite much the same. There certainly no limits, or reason to use a grid for the results.

You also don't even have to use a auto bind control (say list details list).

You can simple drop in controls and lay them out anyway you want.

Say, like this:

```
         <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:300px;float:left">
            <div style="padding:5px;text-align:right">
                <p>Student ID: <asp:TextBox ID="ID" runat="server"               /></p>
                <p>Student Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Student_Name" runat="server"   /></p>
                <p>Honours: <asp:TextBox ID="Honours" runat="server"             /></p>
                <p>Book Price: <asp:TextBox ID="Book_Price" runat="server"       /></p>
                <p>Program: <asp:TextBox ID="Programme" runat="server"           /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So above are just simple controls dropped into the page.

And now our code to fill out above would be:

(same as before, but now in place of a grid bind, or data list bind, we just use code to fill out the controls like this:

```
     if (MyTable.DefaultView.Count > 0)
        {
            // we have a match - display it
            DataRow OneRow = MyTable.DefaultView.ToTable().Rows[0]; 

            ID.Text = OneRow["ID"].ToString();
            Student_Name.Text = OneRow["STudent_Name"].ToString();
            Honours.Text = OneRow["Honours"].ToString();
            Book_Price.Text = OneRow["Book_Price"].ToString();
            Programme.Text = OneRow["Programme"].ToString();
        }
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So sending the results to a grid, or just some code is really quite much the same process. In fact, as you can see, we swapped out the Grid view for a Details view. In other words JUST A CHANGE of 2 lines of code, and we had a details view in place of a gridview.

However, as noted, you obvious want to lay out that final result to any way you want - and not necessary a grid, or even a built in details view.

As you can see in the last example - it was a simple matter to grab/get the results of the filter into one nice simple DataRow object, and from that we just code out setting of the controls we dropped on the page. That sample layout I have could of course be any kind of layout you are able to dream up.